# QGIS and R bridge for spatial analysis

Tags: r, qgis-3

Currently I want to use the R geospatial tools within QGIS for carry out several models related to creation of **random points inside polygons based on attribute values** with the purpose of establishing what is the best R model that depicts poblacional distribution within a determined area.

I have installed currently **QGIS 3.14** and **R 4.0.2** and I have installed **Processinng R Provider plugin** but I haven't achieved that It works.

Can you help me to find some solution or other alternatives for accomplish this analysis type with these two software?

Comment: Looks like there are some tools in the processing toolbox - does this help? https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/training_manual/processing/r_intro.html